# Sending/receiving SMS while sending emails (simultaneously) using a USB dongle modem

Tags: c#, vb.net

What I exactly need is to create a Windows application in VB/C#.NET which is capable of sending/receiving SMS and sending emails using a USB dongle modem, which means email and SMS components must be running simultaneously. (I know how to send/receive SMS and sending Emails in code.) The problem is when sending/receiving SMS it is not possible to send Emails since connection to the internet is not allowed. Is there any way to resolve this issue? Switching from email to SMS and SMS  to email is not what I expect, because receiving SMS should not be interrupted.

However, My ZTE 112 dongle modem software can send/receive SMS while connecting to the internet. If it is so, is there any possibility to do the same with our own code. Additionally I have heard dongle modems supports 2/3 ports, but, how to programmatically implement this in a .net application.

Please let me know your valuable ideas so that I can resolve this issue soon.